# Can't split string from file , _iotextwrapper

Tags: python, file, file-handling

I am trying to create a program. It takes a colour image as a .txt file, in a list 'i'. Now while I have a good idea of what to do for this, I seem to have fallen at the first hurdle.

```
outfile = open("output.txt","w")
with open("ColourImage.txt") as infile:
infile.readline() #to prevent first part from taking the strings
infile.strip()
line = float(infile)
while len(line) != 0:
    f.readline()
    print(line)
```

When I try to do this, I get an error, `'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'strip'` and I have no clue why. and when I tried removing `infile.strip()` I get `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'`.

The file in question is about 20k lines, with each line containing 5 numbers separated a by a comma, for instance:

```
Picture
61, 149, 207, 152, 59
120, 161, 48, 30, 44
77, 132, 16, 13, 30
17, 84, 124, 96, 46
115, 169, 37, 20, 38
70, 33, 88, 62, 37
122, 110, 80, 48, 63
63, 137, 31, 28, 47
```

The first line in the file I am trying to manipulate is a string. The rest afterwards are rows of 5 numbers

Comment: The error is clear, a file object has no method `strip` and cannot be converted to a float. Also a line with 5 floats cannot be converted to a float. What means: the first line is a string?

Comment: edited to make it a bit simpler to understand.

That aside, I know what the issue is, I just don't understand why that's the case. I've used similar code in other pieces of work i've done and haven't run into this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your file looks like this:

```
Picture 
61, 149, 207, 152, 59
```

And the following code is executed:

```
with open("ColourImage.txt") as infile:
    infile.readline()
    line = infile.readline().strip()
    print(line)
    list_of_strings = line.split(", ") 
    print(list_of_strings)
    list_of_floats = [float(a) for a in list_of_strings]
    print(list_of_floats)
```

Output is:

```
61, 149, 207, 152, 59
['61', '149', '207', '152', '59']
[61.0, 149.0, 207.0, 152.0, 59.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`line = float(infile.readline().strip())`
Your code isn't saving what happens to inline. Just manipulating it without saving the result. Of course you'll still run into isssues if you call `float()` on a string like `"45, 96, 50"` without splitting on `,`.